# Shopware 6 Twig - HTML Entity decode

Tags: twig, html-entities, shopware6

I try to decode html entities like `&amp;` which are inside the products description and should be decoded for Feedexport.

As the entities are already inside of the description the `|raw` filter will not work.
It seems that `|html_entity_decode` is not available in Shopware 6 Twig?

Are there any other options to decode entities like `&amp;` in twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than replacing every possible html entity with the decoded value, no.

You could [create a small plugin](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-base-guide) that adds a twig filter for decoding html entities.

```xml
<!-- <plugin root>/src/Resources/config/services.xml -->
<services>
    <service id="SwagExample\Twig\HtmlEntityDecodeExtension" public="true">
        <tag name="twig.extension"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace SwagExample\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class HtmlEntityDecodeExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFilter('html_entity_decode', $this->htmlEntityDecode(...), ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
        ];
    }

    public function htmlEntityDecode(string $text): string
    {
        return html_entity_decode($text);
    }
}
```

Then `product.description|html_entity_decode` etc should work.